# Kafka consumers path in zookeeper is empty?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I use `zkCli.sh` to list the `kafka` paths in `zookeeper`.

By the [Kafka+data+structures+in+Zookeeper](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+data+structures+in+Zookeeper) document,i find all paths in the doc can match the document,except `consumers` path.

Command `ls /consumers`,response `[]`,But [kafka manager of yahoo](https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager) can get consumer info,such as `LogSize`,`Consumer Offset` and so on.

Comment: Do you use the new consumer or the old consumer?

Comment: @amethystic,`org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer` is the new consumer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the new consumer which does not depend on Zookeeper anymore. Zk node '/consumers' is just for old consumers. The reason why you could find consumer info in KafkaManager might because it supports the new consumer already.

Kafka ships with a command kafka-consumer-groups.sh which can be used to check status for both old consumer and new consumer.

Comment: The new consumer has any api to get the consumer groups,and the offset?

Comment: You could invoke ConsumerGroupCommand.main(args). args is a Sting-typed array which contains all the parameters you provide when executing 'kafka-consumer-groups.sh'

Comment: Any java api or rest api?

Comment: This is what you can use in the Java code. No REST APIs for Kafka core or clients functions yet.

Comment: If the new consumer dose not depend on zookeeper,then where is the offset info store?

Comment: It's stored in a special Kafka topic named __consumer_offsets

Comment: I find `ConsumerGroupCommand.main(args)` is a void method,how i to get the response as a string?

Comment: It's just printing the result to stdout. You could check the source code for ConsumerGroupCommand object and try to create such methods.